# How to make phone vibrate for a given number of milliseconds with c#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to make phone (iOS and Android) vibrate for a given number of milliseconds using c#? Right now i'm using `Handheld.Vibrate()` but it vibrates for too long compared to what i need for my game!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/350193/handheldvibrate-duration.html

Comment: I've alread tried that. it seems to not work with c# now. Cannot import android.os and i need it to work on iOS as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with standard Unity tools. If you want to control vibration, then you need to write a separate plugins for each platform (**iOS**, **Android**, etc).